# Hashes and payment

Tags: mining-pools, hashpower

I’m still learning about mining and all, but there’s one thing I still don’t understand. I was checking out the hashflare site and came across the store where you can buy hashes.

What I don’t get it, let’s say I purchase 10 gH/s as an example, which is like $11. Does that mean I pay $11 per every single 10 gH/s, or just a one time payment until the contract is over?